# std :: random_shuffle Java analog

Tags: java, c++, shuffle

I'm not a C ++ specialist, so I'm asking, can anyone know if there is an analogue for `std :: random_shuffle` for Java? So that I also pass 2 arrays

for example `std::random_shuffle ( & mask[0], &mask[81]);`

Comment: What "2 arrays" are you talking about?

Comment: What result do you expect when you pass it two arrays? In Java there is no out of the box method to shuffle an array. However `Collections.shuffle` can shuffle a `List`, so you'd need to convert it. But I don't know what you mean by 2 arrays.

Comment: `std::random_shuffle ( & mask[0], &mask[81]);` does not "pass 2 arrays" - it passes two iterators (in this case regular pointers) from the same array as arguments to the function

Answer (score 1):

For lists you can use `Collections.shuffle()` directly:

```
List<Integer> mask = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) mask.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(mask.subList(0, 81));
```

If you have an array of objects then you can use the following code:

```
Integer[] mask = new Integer[90];
for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) mask[i] = i;
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(mask).subList(0, 81));
```

For arrays of primitive types you would need to code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.shuffle`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
            arr.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(arr);

        for (int elm : arr) {
            System.out.println(elm);
        }
    }
}
```